# using GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 1 in linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, capslock

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
if ( !GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 1 ) {
printf("caps off");
}
else
printf("caps on");
return 0;
}
```

but limited to windows only

how to do this in linux with gcc ?

what is `& 1` in `GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 1` ?

Comment: the `& 1` tests the lowest bit to check if the key is toggled, the highest bit is used to test if its down.

Answer (score 4):

For the most common case of an X11-based desktop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/XKBlib.h>

int main() {
    Display * d = XOpenDisplay((char*)0);

    if (d) {
        unsigned n;

        XkbGetIndicatorState(d, XkbUseCoreKbd, &n);

        printf((n & 1)?"caps on\n":"caps off\n");
    }
}
```

Make sure you have the X11 development headers and compile with:

```
$ gcc -lX11 test.c -o test
```

Run it from a console window in your desktop:

```
$ ./test
caps off
$ ./test
caps on
```

Comment: @SunnySam: This code should work on the vast majority of Linux distributions, as long as you are using a graphical desktop.

Comment: generating lots of error while compiling  in CentOS 5 

already included x11 development headers what to do ?

Comment: @SunnySam: Unfortunately I do not have access to a CentOS system. What errors are you getting?

Comment: can't recognizing  XKBlib.h can you provide me the link of this header file.

Comment: @SunnySam: AFAIK that file is in the libX11-devel rpm - you should be able to use yum to install it...

Comment: We are talking about Centos 5.7, right? Or do you literally mean Centos 5.0? I can only find whatever rpmfind has: http://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libX11-devel&submit=Search+...&system=centos&arch=

Comment: This doesn't check the caps lock state. This checks the caps lock *indicator* (LED) state. Most of the time these two states are the same, except when they are not. Any program can turn any LED on and off without affecting the modifier state.