# C++ X11 get status of the caps lock

Tags: c++, x11, capslock

I need get the state of the CAPS LOCK using C++. I tried to get the state using `XkbGetIndicatorState`, but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What did you try, and in what way didn't it work? Did you try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9010026/204847

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same question but for the NUM_LOCK Key state.
I Modified the code found, to find the CAPS_LOCK state:

Here is the code, I hope this helps:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>


Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(":0");
XKeyboardState x;
printf("led_mask=%lx\n", x.led_mask);
printf("NumLock is %s\n", (x.led_mask & 2) ? "On" : "Off");
printf("CapsLock is %s\n", (x.led_mask & 1) ? "On" : "Off");
```

Answer (score -6):

Try something like below:

```
if ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001)!=0)
  cout<<"Caps Lock ON!";
else
  cout<<"Caps Lock OFF!";
```

Or ([reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/index/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx))

```
Use GetAsyncKeyState with VK_CAPITAL (0x14)
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure X11 doesn't have either of those functions. That looks more like the Windows API.

Comment: The OP is asking about X11. An answer using the Windows API is not useful.

Comment: Please have a look on this link http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/30180-how-to-determine-if-CapsLock-is-on-crossplatform -- it will work for both windows as well as X11  (all cross platform)