# How to get Num Lock and Scroll Lock status

Tags: keyboard, x11, xlib

In my X11 C++ application I need to check modifier keys status. Caps Lock status can be get using `XkbGetIndicatorState`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009775/using-getkeystatevk-capital-1-in-linux/9010026#9010026) is an example. How to get Num Lock and Scroll Lock status ?

Comment: See my comment under the referenced answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `XkbGetState`. It returns a pointer to `XkbStateRec` which contains these fields.

```
  unsigned char            mods;                 /* effective modifiers */
  unsigned char            base_mods;            /* base modifiers */
  unsigned char            latched_mods;         /* latched modifiers */
  unsigned char            locked_mods;          /* locked modifiers */
```

You want to check the effective modifiers mask. Usually Caps Lock is LockMask, Num Lock is Mod2Mask and Scroll Lock is Mod5Mask (from X11/X.h).

Comment: One more thing. Let's assume that Caps Lock, Num Lock or Scroll Lock had been pressed before I have stared my application. Does X server send some event in such case ?

Comment: No, why would it?